# Running java project with hibernate for PostgreSQL and hibernate ogm for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-ogm

I use jpa to access PG from Play. I need to access also MongoDB. Once i add mongo dependencies to the related pom.xml i get runtime exceptions, like:

```
[INFO] --- play2-maven-plugin:1.0.0-beta5:run (default-cli) @ API ---
[INFO] Launching Play! server
 [play] Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 1045
 [play] [warn] o.h.e.j.c.i.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl - HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
 [play] java.lang.AbstractMethodError
 [play]     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:278)
 [play]     at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444)
 [play]     at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:802)
 [play]     at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
 [play]     at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
 [play]     at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
```

While i have these dependencies it works:

```
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Once i add these, it brings runtime exception:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.ogm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ogm-infinispan</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Debug SessionFactoryImpl and check which integrator fails: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/d885f249d92335d63e5a21382327bb33400e2465/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/internal/SessionFactoryImpl.java#L278

Answer (score 0):

The issue resolved by adding more dependencies to pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
        <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.01</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```